# Check if any type of user is signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using devise and have set up helper methods to check if any type of user is signed in. I have player and coach user types and current_player and current_coach are devise methods that exist.

Here is my application_controller:

```
helper_method :current_account, :account_signed_in?

def current_account
  if @current_player 
    @current_account = current_player
  elsif @current_coach 
    @current_account = current_coach
  end
end

def account_signed_in?
  current_account != nil
end
```

The player and coach models are submodels of the user model.

```
class Player < User
end
class Coach < User
end
```

This works (but only if there is a current_player):

```
def current_account
@current_account = current_player
end
```

If I remove the @ from current_player and current_coach I get an error:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 10, expected 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`current_account` stays nil because neither your if condition nor your elsif condition are true. It means that `@current_player` **and** `@current_coach` are nil (or false)

Comment: current_player (without the @) isn't nil but in the if statement I get an error 'wrong number of arguments (given 10, expected 2)' if I remove the @

Comment: show us more code : where do current_player and current_coach comes from ?

Comment: They come from devise. I'm using sti and player and coach are submodels of the user model.